# UPDATE inside a WHILE statement

Tags: php, sql, sql-update

So, I have a page with a bunch of workorders on it. Each workorder is a row in a single table, and gets put on the page with a while() statement. 
I'm trying to update each row with a simple form that I put inside the while(), and an UPDATE/WHERE statement to actually add the information to the table.

Instead of adding it to the specific row, it adds it to Every row. The only thing I can think of is that my WHERE condition is wrong, but I can't seem to figure it out. Maybe it just needs fresh eyes, or maybe I'm heading in Completely the wrong direction.

Also, any specific instructions on security, a better way to do it, etc. would be very helpful. I'm learning PHP on the fly and could use a helping hand. :)

```
<?php

        $query = "SELECT * FROM client_information"; 

        $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());


        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){ 

        $which_ad = $row['ID'];?>

            <b>Name:</b> <? echo $row['billing_name']; ?> <br>
            <b>Job Type:</b> <? echo $row['job_type']; ?> <br>
            <b>Size:</b> <? echo $row['size']; ?> <br>
            <b>Text:</b> <? echo $row['text']; ?> <br>
            <b>Notes:</b> <? echo $notes; ?> <br>

            <br><br>

        <form action="small_update.php" method="POST">
        <strong>Email Message:</strong><br>
        <textarea rows="8" cols="60" name="email_message"></textarea>        
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"></form>


<?
$email_message = htmlspecialchars ("{$_POST['email_message']}", ENT_QUOTES);


if (mysql_errno() != 0) {
die(mysql_error());
}

mysql_query(
"UPDATE client_information
SET email_message='$email_message'

WHERE ID='$which_ad'"
);


if (mysql_errno() != 0) {
die(mysql_error());
}

    }

?>
```

Comment: mysql_fetch_array() is a discourage form of using mysql actions. Please refer to using mysqli_fetch_array() or a PDO for all mysql connections. [mysqli info](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php)

Comment: Every row will get the same `email_message` because you are drawing each of them from the same `$_POST`.  Your original `SELECT` query pulls all rows and your while loop updates all rows from the table with the same value.  Do you mean to use a different value for `email_message`?

Comment: ...which by the way is still vulnerable to SQL injection despite having called `htmlentities()` with `ENT_QUOTES`.  You must at the vary least, call `mysql_real_escape_string()` on `$_POST['email_message']`.  Generally, best practice suggests that you do not call `htmlentities()` or similar _before_ storing in your database, but rather call it only on output. It is recommended to store the _original_ value unmodified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't specify the id in your form:

```
<form action="small_update.php" method="POST">
    <strong>Email Message:</strong><br>
    <textarea rows="8" cols="60" name="email_message"></textarea>
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $which_ad; ?>">  
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

you need to also make sure you know what id was submitted:

```
"UPDATE client_information
SET email_message='$email_message'

WHERE ID='$_POST['id']'"
```

Of course, you're wide open to attacks like this as everyone else is saying. You need to look into mysqli or pdo to sanitize your input...

Ans also upon inspection you're evaluating your post data in the loop. Don't do that. Just do your evaluation before everything else is processed on the page...

```
<?php
if($_POST)
{
    //run processing here
}

// do your fetch code here and display the forms...
```

Comment: Thanks for that! I had no idea I had to specify the id Inside the form too. And thanks for all the tips on security, etc. :)